# PHP cURL URL Not Found

Tags: php, curl

I am new to using cURL....whenever I run this I get a page that says "The requested URL /files/ was not found on this server." But, if I go to the link on a browser then it shows up. Please assist. I have looked at similar questions but could not find a solution to my problem.

```php
<?php
$username="user"; 
$password="pass"; 
$url="http://website.com/login/"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "login=$username&pass=$password";


//set the directory for the cookie using defined document root var
$dir = DOC_ROOT;

//the info per user with custom func. 
$path = $dir;

//login form action url 

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/files/");
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$postdata = array(
  'login' => $username,
  'pass' => $password
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

Comment: still get the same result

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
```

**to**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
```

---

Make sure you've **write permission** on the current dir so `curl` can create the cookie file `cookie.txt`

you should end-up with something like :

```
<?php
$username="user"; 
$password="pass"; 
$url_login="http://website.com/login/"; 
$url_files="http://website.com/files/"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "login=$username&pass=$password";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_files);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

---

**NOTE:**

Sometimes, less is more.

Comment: i changed it but get the same error. how do i change permissions?

Comment: Create a file named `cookies.txt` on the same folder as the script, then, via ftp, right click on cookies.txt and check all permissions. You have access to a shell  run `chmod 777 cookies.txt`

Comment: i changed it to the php code you said and it is the same result. i can see cookie.txt being generated with correct values. changed 777 and still same issue

Comment: I guess you're missing some value on the request but I'm not sure if I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided http://website.com/files/ has a redirection, so CURL has to have option enabled to follow redirects.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

While in your code you have

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```

`0` means `false`, so you are disabling following on HTTP 30x

Comment: thats not the actual site

Comment: But if you enable the redirection, does it help? You could also do some testing in command line `curl`.

Comment: i changed it to true, it didnt make a difference. i can see that it successfully logs in and stores the cookie. i dont understand why it does show the page that has the files